# ENYOJS: Set focus on default element on page render

Tags: javascript, enyo

Moonstone Spotlight.

How do I set focus to  an element (button etc) after render ?

I've tried    nameOfElement.focus()  and that does not seem to work.

```
   rendered : function(){
      this.inherited(arguments);
      var buttonreference = this.$.iconbackbuttonmaster;
      buttonreference.focus();
    }
```

Here is a >>>> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fabii23/uam83z55/4/)

Comment: Don't forget to use 'var' in front of buttonreference unless you want to be creating global variables!

Comment: Spotlight focus is different from DOM focus, which is why you need to use the answer you got from the forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically forcing a `Spotlight` focus of a `Moonstone` element requires exercising caution as the general behavior dictates that when in pointer mode, only items hovered by the pointer should be focused, otherwise you end up with the scenario where you can have multiple controls on the screen with `Spotlight` focus. If necessary, you can usually get around this built-in logic by explicitly disabling pointer mode, but this should force you to pause and reconsider why you are programmatically spotting in the first place. Here is an example that should accomplish what you want (http://jsfiddle.net/aarontam/uam83z55/5/):

```
enyo.create({
    components: [
        {name: 'myButton', kind: 'moon.Button', content: 'button to focus'}
    ],
    rendered: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        enyo.Spotlight.setPointerMode(false);
        enyo.Spotlight.spot(this.$.myButton);
    }
}).renderInto(document.body);
```

Alternatively, you could add the `spotlight` class to your control, though the onus would be on the developer to manage removal of the class as appropriate (http://jsfiddle.net/aarontam/uam83z55/6/):

```
enyo.create({
    components: [
        {name: 'myButton', kind: 'moon.Button', content: 'button to focus', classes: 'spotlight'}
    ]
}).renderInto(document.body);
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling .focus() should work.

Did you remember to add

```
this.inherited(arguments);
```

to your rendered function to call the overridden render function?

Comment: Based on another question, it sounds like you might be using Spotlight (and Moonstone?). If you want it to be spotted, you might want to use Spotlight's `defaultControl` to cause it to spot the control at startup. Additionally, you can set Spotlight focus by calling `enyo.Spotlight.spot(<control>)`

Comment: Yes I just forgot to include it in my snippet on here.

Comment: @Pre101 Thanks this helps in setting the default spotlight on my button when I navigate to it. How do I highlight (focus) without having to navigate to it first ?

Answer (score 3):

Answer courtesy of aarontam on Enyo forums : [spotlight question](http://forums.enyojs.com/discussion/comment/9176#Comment_9176)

Hi there, you do not need to specify spotlight:true for a moon.Button as it is already Spotlight-enabled. Programmatically forcing a Spotlight focus of a Moonstone element can be tricky as the general rule is that when in pointer mode, only items hovered by the pointer should be focused, otherwise you end up with the scenario where you have two disparate controls on the screen with Spotlight focus. You can, at times, get around this by disabling pointer mode, but this should force you to pause and reconsider why you are programmatically spotting in the first place.

```
enyo.create({
    components: [
        {name: 'myButton', kind: 'moon.Button', content: 'button to focus'}
    ],
    rendered: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        enyo.Spotlight.setPointerMode(false);
        enyo.Spotlight.spot(this.$.myButton);
    }

}).renderInto(document.body);
```

Here is an example that should accomplish what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/aarontam/uam83z55/5/

Alternatively, you could add the "spotlight" class to your button as so, though the ball would then be in your court to manage removal of the class as appropriate:

http://jsfiddle.net/aarontam/uam83z55/6/

Comment: @aarontam Hey!! Post the above as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you wait until the page is loaded before trying to do it:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("idOfElement").focus();
};
```

Comment: No that does not work ,I am using enyojs framework .

Comment: I don't know anything about Enyo, but it seems surprising that it would prevent you from using normal Javascript functions in addition to its framework options.

Comment: That will work as well, just see Art Dahm's answer to see why the button was not working.